# Regular expressions to match word with three b, correct form?

Tags: regex

I find this very ambiguous and vague and I would love to understand

I have these strings

```
abbb
bbb
aaaabaaabaaabaaabaaabaaab
babba
bbbaaaa
aaaaabbaba
```

And they are all valid because contains multiple of `b`, then I use:

- `(a*ba*ba*ba*)*` and this matches them all
- `(a*ba*ba*b)*a*` this match them all as well
- `a*(ba*ba*ba*)*` same as above

Are these really all the same? Or there are edge cases that I am not seeing?

Comment: What's the real goal ? Why those weird regular expressions ?

Comment: Having `a*` at the start or end of a regex is useless.

Comment: Please read the description of the tags you use. I removed one. The other one tells you to specify the language you use (yes, regular expression greatly differ between languages)

Comment: These three regexes are exactly equivalent inasmuch as they match/fail to match exactly the same strings (assuming you're forcing them to match the *entire* input, not just a substring of the input.

Comment: @dystroy: If the regex is used with, say, Java's `matches()` method, then presence/absence of `a*` at these positions is relevant.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Oh yes, the infamous Java regex methods... You're right (we could also cite the pattern attribute in HTML inputs). This question can only make sense with a proper tag.

Comment: There are the same except they don't catch the same value in capture group.

Comment: All of your regexes match the empty string and require b's to come in *sets* of 3's, not just that there should be 3 b's in a string in order to get a match. This is kind of weird. Otherwise, as Tim says, they match the same inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all of your regexes match the empty string, which doesn't have 3 b's.

This one,

```
(a*ba*ba*ba*)*
```

does not match `aa`. But the following match `aa`, and they are also equivalent:

```
(a*ba*ba*b)*a*
a*(ba*ba*ba*)*
```

If you want to force at least 3 b's, you have to take the b's out of the Kleene star:

```
(a|b)*b(a|b)*b(a|b)*b(a|b)*
```

Comment: Your first example explains exactly the difference I was looking for, thanks. Although I think that your last example won't work. in that way with the b in (a|b), you can have infinitely many b's and not multiple of b

Answer (score 1):

`*` is zero or more. So,

even if you match using a regex like the ones below

```
(d*ef*gg*hi*)*
(s*o*m*e*t*h*i*n*g*)
```

etc.

they will match

```
(a*ba*ba*ba*)*
```

( match a word which may have an a or not or many a's then a b and then 0 or more a's and then a b and then 0 or more a's and one b and then 0 or more a's ) zero or more of this kind of match.. **Its okay if we dont find a match** thats what you want to say.

Similarly for your second case:

```
(a*ba*ba*b)*a*
```

(0 or more `a` and then a `b` and then 0 or more a and then a `b` then 0 or more a and then a `b`) 0 or more of this and zero or more of a after that.

So your regex basically matches so many `0` presence conditions, thats why you are not able to find the clear difference. better use `+` instead of `*`. A `+` quatifier will make the match only of the character is present at least `1` or more times.

you can play around with regex on this site here : http://regex101.com/r/rM5zQ1

for basic learnings regexone will be really helpful for you.

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 1):

You should use `+` after the group instead of `*`, or else an empty string would be accepted:

```
(a*ba*ba*ba*)+
```

Although this would only allow multiples of 3. If you want at least 3 and any number of extras, it would be:

```
a*ba*ba*b(a|b)*
```

This works for those requirements. But it isn't a good approach. In your example you are searching for "a" and "b", which are single character patterns, and it's already an unreasonably long expression for the simple rule "has 3 b's" in my opinion. But what if the patterns were more complex? You would need to repeat them at least 3 times, making it even more unwieldy.

And what if the rules change slightly? If you wanted to match a *maximum* instead of a *minimum* number of b's, it would become even more complex / repetitive, because your only choice would be to combine the patterns for each possible number (1, 2, 3):

```
(a*ba*|a*ba*ba*|a*ba*ba*ba*)
```

Or if you decide the word must be a certain length, it actually becomes impossible, short of listing every permutation (for a 7 letter word, `ba{3}bab`, `a{2}babab`, `b{3}a{4}` etc.).

So, I think a better way to solve this is to match the basic generic pattern, then examine the *results* of the match to check the counts. For example, just match a "word":

```
(a|b)+
```

Then on the matching text, match b:

```
b
```

and test the number of matches and/or length of text as needed. Each pattern is only repeated a maximum of twice, and your code can easily be adapted to different requirements.